# Well-definedness of uncomputable functions.

Tags: set-theory, computability, foundations

I have been reading about Rayo's function and uncomputable functions in general, and have gotten very confused. There is apparently concern over the well-definedness of Rayo's function, but I never had any doubt that things such as the busy beaver function were well-defined. Then I read [this article](http://jdh.hamkins.org/largest-number-contest/) where it was stated that two numbers described by uncomputable functions like BB might be incomparable within a certain system of axioms - it could be independent of the system which one was larger. This was taken to mean that one might not be larger than the other at all. I took this to suggest that even a simple uncomputable function like BB(n) could be undefined in a sense.

However, it seems to me that, given two numbers, it should always be possible to decide which is bigger. It also seems like the busy beaver function should be well-defined since it is making a precise statement about machines which could theoretically be implemented in the physical world.

So, are uncomputable functions well-defined in general? What characteristics would make one well-defined or not, and is there something I'm conceptually missing in the way that I am approaching these questions? Thank you for helping me understand!

Comment: Assuming you are not an ultra-finitist, the busy beaver function is definitely well-defined mathematically. Well-definedness as an integer-valued function is not the same as being uncomputable

Comment: You are able to always tell which number I should bigger, assuming a universe with nigh infinite data storage and assuming you have a lot of spare time (and I mean a lot)...

Comment: @L.McDonald This depends on what you mean by 'given two numbers'. If the meaning is 'given two properties that each provably define a unique number', then it is not necessarily effectively decidable which number is bigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The busy-beaver-function is well-defined because every halting turing machine can only write a finite number of ones on the tape, hence there must be a champion, and $bb(n)$ is the number of ones this champion writes down.

But the busy-beaver-function is not computable because we cannot determine which turing machines halt and which do not. This (and only this) prevents us from determining the busy-beaver-champion and therefore determining $bb(n)$ in general.

"Computable" means that there is an algorithm being able for every n to either determine $f(n)$ or determine that $f(n)$ is not defined.

"Well-defined" means that there is a description guaranteeing that for every $n$ there is either only one possible value $f(n)$ or that the function is not defined.  (It is not necessary that this $f(n)$ can actually be determined , if $f(n)$ is defined.)

Comment: "Computable" means that there is an algorithm being able to determine f(n) for every n. Not really, partial functions are allowed.

Comment: @Wuestenfux I edited the question, although I think that the question refers rather to functions defined everywhere.

Comment: @Peter I agree that “total recursive function” is a perfectly reasonable interpretation of ‘computable’ for the purposes of this question, since BB is total recursive. But your edit to include the partial recursive case is wrong. The algorithm cannot determine if $f(n)$ is undefined... in that case it will just run forever, never determining anything.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Not in the case of a computable function.

Comment: @Peter No, the algorithm not halting on inputs where the function is undefined is the definition of a partial recursive function. (aka what is usually referred to as a computable function). There's no point allowing the function to be undefined on certain inputs if the algorithm is going to halt on every input... Besides, the fact that the algorithm might not halt is what makes things interesting.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Does that mean That Wuestenfux's comment is wrong ? Must a computable function be defined everywhere ? If not, why can we call a function computable, if we cannot decide whether it is defined at some point ?

Comment: @Peter There are two notions here, partial recursive and total recursive, and 'computable' can mean either depending on context. Total recursive means a total function for which there is a Turing machine that computes $f(n)$ given any input $n.$ Partial recursive means a partial function where there is a TM that computes $f(n)$ for any input $n$ at which the function is defined, otherwise does not halt. Computable is often defined to mean partial recursive function rather than total (in fact in my experience it's somewhat more common), I imagine because these exactly correspond to algorithms.

Comment: @Peter Wuestenfux isn't wrong per se, they're just insisting on using 'computable' to mean partial recursive, perhaps unaware that people often use it to mean total recursive. I didn't think that was particularly useful here since the sense I thought total was the most natural definition to use for the purposes of this question, and your answer didn't seem problematic to me before the edit.

Comment: @Peter (Also, looking at my first comment I see I made a confusing typo: I meant "BB is a total function," not "BB is total recursive.")

Comment: @Peter I think using computable for a program halting on all inputs is fine. I think it is quite commonly used. For example, the following are equivalent: (a1) computable (a2) recursive (a3) total computable (a4) total recursive. Similarly, the following are also equivalent: (b1) partial computable (b2) partial recursive. Though there are probably some sources that use "computable" to mean "partial computable" and, quite honestly, I think that kind of usage is very confusing (and I very rarely complain about terminology). There are only a couple of exceptions to it (mentioned in next comment).

Comment: Sometimes when people say "collection of computable functions", it can mean "collection of partial computable functions". Otherwise I think the normal association of "computable" with "total computable" is fine. Of course it can be a bit context dependent occasionally so using "total computable" for emphasis can be useful at times. Also, "algorithm" is generally associated with a function halting on all inputs. One thing though, the general convention for a partial computable function is to take it as "undefined" only on those input values for which it does not halt. (cont.)

Comment: So "normally", when a total comptuable function (also called algorithm normally.... unless the context makes it clear that something else is meant) computes a function, the function is presumed to be defined for all values in its domain. Finally note that "partial computable functions" are, by convention, meant to include all functions that may or may not halt on all the inputs. In other words, the collection of partial computable functions contains collection of total compuable functions as strict subset.

Comment: In summary, all of this can be slightly context dependent of course, but generally speaking what I said before holds. For example, if you have a partial function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ and that function happens to be (partial) computable, then by default convention usually when you write a program for it then you would set it up so it doesn't halt on inputs where the function is partial. In practice (say a real world program), if the locations/inputs where the said function is partial are trivial/easy, you might set-up a different convention (but you would have to describe that).

Comment: @SSequence Thank you! I agree with your comments.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to separate. First, the definition of functions. A function $f:A\rightarrow B$ is a relation $f\subseteq A\times B$ which is both left-total and right-unique.

Second, the computability of a function. Here one generally considers (partial) functions $f:{\Bbb N}_0^k\rightarrow{\Bbb N}_0$. The question is whether there is an algorithm computing the function. By the thesis of Church, the computable functions are exactly those that are partially recursive.

Note that the number of computable functions is denumerable as they correspond to the set of C-programs and the set of C-programs (as words over the keyboard alphabet) is denumerable.