# Examples of computable sequence of rational numbers

Tags: recursion, computability

I am a beginner to computability theory and curently reading [Pour-El and Richard Computability in Analysis and Physics, Chapter $0$](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pl/1235422917).

At page $14,$ they provided a definition for computable sequence of rational numbers:

> A sequence $\{r_n\}$ of rational numbers is computable if there exist three recursive functions $a,b,s$ from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ such that $b(k)\neq 0$ for all $k$ and 
>   $$r_k = (-1)^{s(k)}\frac{a(k)}{b(k)} \quad \text{for all }k.$$

I have trouble understanding the definition above.
In particular,

> Question: What are some examples of computable sequence of rational numbers?

Comment: a(k) = 1; b(k) = 1; s(k) = 0

Comment: @JohnDvorak It will give a sequence of all $1.$

Comment: @JohnDvorak May I know a nonrecursive function?

Comment: @Idonknow What about $a(k)=k+1$, $b(k)=k+2$, $s(k)=0$. This gives the sequence (of rationals) $1/2,2/3,3/4,4/5,5/6,...$ which  converges to $1$.

Comment: Actually I am confused about the meaning of recursive functions. Can anyone give a nonrecursive function?

Comment: @Idonknow "recursive functions" are just synonymous with "computable functions". They are just a generalisation of "primitive recursive functions" by adding a minimalisation operation (you can find a lot of material on it I think). You might also want to look at comments I wrote in this topic (under one of the answers): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3076575.

Comment: That book assumes you are already familiar with computability theory.  That is why they begin with "computable real numbers" without talking about computability. You should start by getting a basic understanding of computability on its own before trying to apply it in more complicated situations. Otherwise, it is like trying to learn about differential equations before learning basic calculus.

Comment: @CarlMummert Thanks for pointing out. May you suggest a few books on computability theory so that I can read Pour-El's book without trouble? Thanks.

Comment: There is an introductory book by Cooper that is a little.idiosyncratic in writing style but conveys good intuition. 
The book by Weber is also good, and not too long . There is a more recent book by Enderton that is also good, but he doesn't focus as much on applications of computability.